# Not expanding the navigation property

Tags: breeze

I am using Entity Framework only for metadata generation, I am experiencing an issue that the breeze query is not expanding the navigation property. In this many-to-many relationship example, the property StudentsCourses in Student is returned as null in the breeze query results. Could it be because I am not using EF for data access? Thanks!

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Student")]
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentsCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Course")]
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentsCourses { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    //[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    //[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseID")]
    [InverseProperty("StudentsCourses")]
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentID")]
    [InverseProperty("StudentsCourses")]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.StudentsCourses).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.StudentID);
    }
}

class StudentCourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<StudentCourse>
{
    public StudentCourseMap()
    {
        HasKey(pc => new { pc.CourseID, pc.StudentID });
        Property(pc => pc.CourseID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(pc => pc.StudentID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class SchoolController : ApiController
{
    private readonly SchoolRepository _repository;

    public SchoolController() : this(null) { }

    public SchoolController(SchoolRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository ?? new SchoolRepository();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _repository.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Student> Students()
    {
        return _repository.Students;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<StudentCourse> StudentsCourses()
    {
        return _repository.StudentsCourses;
    }
}
```

The implementation of SchoolRepository.Students:

```
public IQueryable<Student> Students
{
    get
    {
        return SchoolContext.Students().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

The breeze query:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Students")
        .where("Name", "==", "H")
        .expand("StudentsCourses");
```

Comment: What does your api controller look like?

Comment: I have just included the api controller as shown above, thanks!

Comment: what's the implementation of `SchoolRepository.Students`?

Comment: The implementation of SchoolRepository.Students has been included, thanks!

Comment: I don't see the problem- have a look at the troubleshooting tips in the "when .expand(...) fails" section of this page:
http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-result-debugging#expand

Comment: I feel that it is because I am not using EF for data access and so I can't use the .include("StudentsCourses") in the SchoolRepository, I think I need to have an implementation for it?

Comment: Oh right- I didn't read that thoroughly.  You need EF if you want breeze to handle the expansion automatically.  You could create another method on your controller "StudentsAndCourses" and use that when you want the expanded data.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for your help! Unable to use the expansion automatically is not ideal, that means I can't navigate to those properties easily by using a breeze query. :(

Comment: Can't use "expand" if your data access layer doesn't support LINQ `include`. That's just "physics". But what's wrong with a "StudentsAndCourses" endpoint that does the expand within the server method? Once the query results are materialized as entities on the Breeze client, you'll be able to navigate there.

Comment: @Ward Thanks for replying! StudentsAndCourses endpoint works too, it would be great if I could do the eager loading and it knows where to populate the results, the relationship settings come into effect so I don't need to do the mapping deliberately on the server side.

Comment: That's easy ... Just throw the courses into a bag and breeze will wire them up client side. Same technique as for " lookups". Will explain a bit more in an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your FIRST challenge lies in conveying the query information from the client to the server such that your particular data access technology can do the right thing.

You're not using EF. You were not clear about whether you can use LINQ to access the data that you want. I gather by looking at your `Students` controller method that you are NOT applying the LINQ expression on your data tier:

```
public IQueryable<Student> Students
{
    get
    {
        return SchoolContext.Students().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

You are pulling **EVERY student in your database** into server memory and then letting Web API apply the LINQ query to whittle it down before shipping students over the wire.

That's OK if you don't have a lot of students. That's awful if you do.

It will be even more awful if you try to pull all of their Courses into server memory at the same time.

It appears from your comments that you have additional difficulties trying *on the server* to wire up the navigation properties between students and their course maps and between those maps and the courses. Apparently your data access layer doesn't do this for you or there is some other impediment that you haven't mentioned.

I might have a more apt solution for you if I knew more about your actual data access options.

It would also help to know how you actually use this API. If you don't need the full power of LINQ (or can't really use it), maybe you should simply create the endpoint that you need.

### Web API Controller

Let's suppose - I'm guessing now - that you only ever query for "Students and their courses" with one or two filter criteria and never with ordering or paging.

Your example - "*Get all students whose name starts with 'H' and get their courses*" - that sounds kind of artificial to me. But I'll bite. Let's also support filtering by `StudentID`

You could write a Web API controller method that takes these two criteria as parameters. Your repository doesn't have to wire everything together. It just has to know how to apply the selection criteria. Here's *one* possibility.

```
[HttpGet]
public object StudentsAndCourses(int? studentId, string? studentName)
{
    var students = _repository.GetStudents(studentId, studentName);

    // once we know the students, we can get the course maps
    var courseMaps = _repository.GetCourseMaps(students);

    // now get the courses for those maps
    var courses = _repository.GetCourses(courseMaps);

    return new { students, courseMaps, courses};
}
```

As you can see, I'm just throwing the entities you need into a bag and sending the bag to the client. This method does not return an `IQueryable`. Therefore, the OData query string (if there were one) is effectively ignored. The Web API does not attempt to compose or apply a LINQ expression from an OData query string.

> In an effort to keep this example relatively simple, I'm not talking about Breeze's ability to *represent a query as a JSON object*.
>
> That would be ideal if you *really* needed rich query semantics on the server but couldn't use LINQ. It's much easier to parse the Breeze JSON representation of a query than it is to to tear apart the OData URL query string or spelunk .NET LINQ expression trees.
>
> It's overkill if you don't need that richness ... and I'll assume that you don't.

### Breeze Client

Let's query by student name

```
return EntityQuery.from('StudentsAndCourses')
    .withParameters({studentName: 'H'})
    .using(manager).execute()
    .then(success).catch(handleFail);
```

And now query by student ID

```
return EntityQuery.from('StudentsAndCourses')
    .withParameters({studentId: 42})
    .using(manager).execute()
    .then(success).catch(handleFail);
```

The `success` callback is the same for both. It's job is to return the selected Student(s) to the caller:

```
function success(data) {
    return data.results.students
}
```

The `CourseMap` and `Course` entities are also in the `data.results` bag. You don't care. You are content that Breeze discovered these while processing the bag and wired up the related entities.

Suppose that you had a method in your client-side `dataservice` called `getStudentInfoById`. You call it from within your ViewModel like so:

```
vm.student;
...
dataservice.getStudentInfoById().then(function(student) {
    vm.student = student;
});
```

When the query succeeds, the following (Angular model) properties will be populated

```
vm.student;
vm.student.StudentCourses;
vm.student.StudentCourses[0].Course;
```

You can also see all courses that you've retrieved with this or a similar query:

```
manager.getEntities(['Course']);
```

If you don't have too many courses, you might just get them all upfront when your app starts. Then you can simplify the `StudentsAndCourses` controller method such that it returns only `Students` and their `StudentCourse` maps.

I leave this to you as an exercise.

### Do you really need EF Metadata generation?

I'll bet that your model is much more complicated than the one shown in your question.

If your model is actually reasonably small, you might consider writing the [metadata by hand](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) on the client. You might find it to be both easy and more simple.

Comment: Much appreciated for your detailed example. I underestimated Breeze, I have done a test, it did wire up the the navigation properties, that is awesome!! I saw the Breeze example for writing the metadata by hand, I used EF instead to generate metadata I think that is easier. I have another question, the navigation property looping, Student -> StudentCourses -> Student -> StudentCourses, is it a problem or it is fine? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am still designing the database, there are only two student records so I just return all. There will be filtering parameters for sure.

Comment: Circular references are not a problem for Breeze ... far from it ... they are expected!  Is there a reason you aren't using EF and SQL Server? It's pretty much the happy path for folks programming in .NET and you are using the Web API apparently

Comment: I am using SQL Server and Web API, but not EF because it is heavy, it forces foreign key relationship, for performance purpose I store some foreign key data as normal data, and I have to keep data integrity to avoid dummy data. Can I please ask one last question, as circular references are not a problem, is there a potential issue that cascade delete would delete more data than it should? Thanks!

Comment: I confess I have no idea what people mean when they call S/W "heavy". I don't understand "awesome" either. I suppose by "FK data as normal data" you mean that your denormalize some of your data. That's fine; you just have to manage it. That's not an EF issue. So you lost me here. Perhaps you are misinformed? Well ... whatever ... that's certainly a topic for some other forum.

Comment: Breeze does not perform cascade deletes on the client nor does it do anything to enforce or hinder cascade deletes on the server. On the client you delete exactly (and only) what you choose to delete.  If your server performs cascade deletes, you may have to mimic that on your client (e.g., by discarding entities that you know were cascade deleted on the server). I personally prefer to manage deletes on both sides rather than allow cascade deletes. Actually, i strive to avoid deleting all together; I'd rather mark inactive.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I put it wrong, I mean all the tables need a primary key. Compared with micro ORMs, EF is heavy. Surely you know the pros, cons and restrictions of using EF.  [Should we use Entity Framework?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115136/should-we-use-entity-framework)

Comment: That's a very old post ... 2011 ... and in my experience even then the pros far outweighed the cons for most apps. I'd rather focus on the business problem than mess around with the ORM. EF has proven itself worthy. Why mess around?

Comment: Your are right, EF removes the work to build the DAL, and I agree with focusing on the business side. I can make a switch back to EF for simple DAL design and its full capacity with breeze, and the "expansion" would not be a problem. Thanks!